# "! Missing endcsname inserted." encountered after MiKTeX version 21.3

Tags: pdftex, miktex

I publish code that generates LaTeX files which are then converted to a PDF (Nautical Almanacs).

This all worked flawlessly for over 6 years up to and including MiKTeX version 21.3. With MiKTeX version 21.7 **on Windows 10** `pdflatex filename.tex` crashes and it has to do with the `\includegraphics` line on the Title Page. I reported this as a MiKTeX issue but was told *"This is not a MiKTeX-specific issue."* Note that I do not have this issue in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS using Tex Live.

A Sample LaTeX script to reproduce this error is here:

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage[nomarginpar, top=10mm, bottom=15mm, left=10mm, right=10mm]{geometry}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}   % for \includegraphics
\begin{document}
% for the title page only...
\newgeometry{nomarginpar, top=21mm, bottom=15mm, left=10mm, right=10mm}
    \begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
    \textsc{\Large Generated using Ephem and Skyfield}\\
    \large http://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/\\[0.7cm]
    % TRIM values: left bottom right top
    \includegraphics[clip, keepaspectratio, trim=12mm 20cm 12mm 21mm, width=0.92\textwidth]{C:\\Python39\\Lib\\site-packages\\skyalmanac\\data\\A4chart0-180_P.pdf}\\[0.3cm]
    \includegraphics[clip, keepaspectratio, trim=12mm 20cm 12mm 21mm, width=0.92\textwidth]{C:\\Python39\\Lib\\site-packages\\skyalmanac\\data\\A4chart180-360_P.pdf}\\[1.5cm]
    \textsc{\huge The Nautical Almanac}\\[1.0cm]
    \HRule \\[0.5cm]
    { \Huge \bfseries 2021}\\[0.2cm]
    \HRule \\
    \begin{center}\begin{tabular}[t]{rl}
    \large\emph{Author:} & \large Andrew \textsc{Bauer}\\
    \large\emph{Original concept from:} & \large Enno \textsc{Rodegerdts}\\
    \end{tabular}\end{center}
    {\large \today}
    \HRule \\[0.2cm]
    \end{center}
    \begin{description}\footnotesize
    \item[Disclaimer:] some text
    \end{description}
\end{titlepage}
\restoregeometry    % so it does not affect the rest of the pages
\end{document}
```

(Unfortunately this forum doesn't allow me to upload the two PDF image files referenced above.)

After some internet research and some experimenting, I came across a "solution" (which I prefer to call a workaround). Simply change the double backslashes in the `\includegraphics` path to a single forward slash. The following script works correctly **on Windows 10**:

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage[nomarginpar, top=10mm, bottom=15mm, left=10mm, right=10mm]{geometry}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}   % for \includegraphics
\begin{document}
% for the title page only...
\newgeometry{nomarginpar, top=21mm, bottom=15mm, left=10mm, right=10mm}
    \begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
    \textsc{\Large Generated using Ephem and Skyfield}\\
    \large http://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/\\[0.7cm]
    % TRIM values: left bottom right top
    \includegraphics[clip, keepaspectratio, trim=12mm 20cm 12mm 21mm, width=0.92\textwidth]{C:/Python39/Lib/site-packages/skyalmanac/data/A4chart0-180_P.pdf}\\[0.3cm]
    \includegraphics[clip, keepaspectratio, trim=12mm 20cm 12mm 21mm, width=0.92\textwidth]{C:/Python39/Lib/site-packages/skyalmanac/data/A4chart180-360_P.pdf}\\[1.5cm]
    \textsc{\huge The Nautical Almanac}\\[1.0cm]
    \HRule \\[0.5cm]
    { \Huge \bfseries 2021}\\[0.2cm]
    \HRule \\
    \begin{center}\begin{tabular}[t]{rl}
    \large\emph{Author:} & \large Andrew \textsc{Bauer}\\
    \large\emph{Original concept from:} & \large Enno \textsc{Rodegerdts}\\
    \end{tabular}\end{center}
    {\large \today}
    \HRule \\[0.2cm]
    \end{center}
    \begin{description}\footnotesize
    \item[Disclaimer:] some text
    \end{description}
\end{titlepage}
\restoregeometry    % so it does not affect the rest of the pages
\end{document}
```

Now to my questions:

- would you still call this a bug in MiKTeX? Remember that MiKTeX versions <= 21.3 work fine.
- Would you claim that a Windows path should **not** contain double backslashes?
- If MiKTeX is not to blame, where can I post this issue so that it gets fixed?

Your assistance is *greatly appreciated* after I was shunned by the MiKTeX issue-reporting page on GitHub.

**UPDATE**

This problem was reported as MiKTeX issue #882. After it was closed I responded thus:

> Okay... it worked in MiKTeX 21.3 and it fails in MiKTeX 21.7, so
> somewhere in between the problem occurred. I have no idea where to
> look next. Is this an issue that you can ignore without even a message
> to the offending party? I would really appreciate your expert advice
> and your comment on "can double backslash with a vertical spacing
> argument just fail and be ignored?". Is it a problem with
> \includegraphics ? MiKTeX has worked wonderfully for the past 7 years
> or so.

Now the thread is locked with the comment:

> MiKTeX locked as too heated and limited conversation to collaborators
> 23 hours ago

I'm amazed!

Comment: well I never used `\\ `  in pathes and I'm quite surprised that you claim that it ever worked.  Pathes in tex should always use slash.

Comment: I  can not see how \\ could ever work in a latex path. the documented path separator is /

Comment: have you seen any documentation anywhere that suggests that `\\ ` could be used as a path separator? If so we could try to get that documentation fixed.

Comment: I probably picked "\\" as Windows paths use backslash as opposed to "/" in Linux. It sounded logical to me and it always worked (and still works in Tex Live). However I am delighted that David and Ulrike responded with professional comments. I know you are the experts and if you say one should use a forward slash also in Windows paths, then I will adapt my code immediately. Thanks for your prompt and friendly support ... quite the opposite of MiKTeX support. (A .tex file I generate contains over 64.000 lines so I have to create it with Python).